# Apply New Bitbucket Cloud Service Connection to Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

In Azure Devops, I had a Bitbucket service connection that was created when a bitbucket pipeline was created using the "Bitbucket Cloud" option. That service connection was then deleted. How do I assign a new service connection to the pipeline? When I try to edit the pipeline I get the following error:
[image: Edit Pipeline Error]

If I try to click "Settings" for the pipeline I get the following error:

> Service connection <Guid> not found in the project <Guid>

Is my only option to re-create the pipeline?